# This jquery lookup is not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".pagination.postpagination a").click(function(event) {
            // Populate the hidden page_number field and submit the search form.
            event.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('data-page-number');
            $("#id_page_number").val(page);
            $("#customer-search-form").submit();
        });
```

For some reason the customer search from does not fire unless there is a 'console.log()' before or after that line for customer search. Any ideas?  I am not a JS programmer but am helping someone on our team.  The lookup is failing for some reason I think.  Thanks!

Comment: press F12, find the tab with network requests, refresh the page, and click the link.
do you see a request go out to your server?
does the `form` element have an `action` attribute?

Comment: check for errors in the console. (F12 - console)

Comment: OK the programmer I am working with is not yet available but I will try this thanks Plato and Guido!  Will let you know..

Comment: Do you know if the 'a' tag is being created dynamically (by javascript)? if so, you might wanna try $('body').on('click', '.pagination.postpagination a', function(event){ .... }

Comment: OK so there is no request to the server.  There is an action attribute.  We did a test using the form's .submit() function to aleart a message which is firing.  So JS is 'submitting' the form and it's not actually creating a request to the server.  I will check on the 'a'tag that Sam mentioned as well.  Thanks!

Comment: The 'a' tag is in the initial markup and is not created by the JS.  Apparently the JS 'hijacks' a link click, stops the default behavior, fills a hidden form field, and submits the form. So the selector is correct and grabs the form DOM element, and the submit seems to fire the JS submit event, but there's no request sent to the server for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for `#customer-search-form`?

Comment: Yes I will get this posted tomorrow morning when I have access to the code base again- thanks Johnny!

Comment: Here is the HTML for the customer search form:                 <form  action="/admin/customers/search/" id="customer-search-form" method="post" >

Comment: The name of the button being "submit" was conflicting with the button type "submit"  thanks everyone for your help!